# String comparison using Like an wildcard not working

Tags: excel, wildcard, sql-like, vba

I have data in some cells in column B that look like Id# plus some number e.g 'Id# 85'

All the other cells have names in them FirstName LastName

I need to find the cells that have Id# in them, I am trying the following, but not working

Thanks

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Elements")

  With ws
  For i = 2 To 180
    If .Cells(i, "B").Text Like "Id#" & "*" Then Do something
  Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `instr`?

Comment: Is ID capitalized in your chart? `Like` defaults to `compare binary`, which will return false if you compare "ID*" and "Id*". If you don't want the comparison to be case-sensitive, use `Option Compare Text`.

Comment: Also, you may want to use `.Value` or `.Value2` instead of using `.Text`. `.Text` can return wonky values if the contents of the cell are too long to display on screen.

Comment: I just got it, it was the `#` not working with the `*`

Comment: `#` is a wildcard in and of itself.  Use the `*` only.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Elements")

    With ws
        For i = 2 To 180
            If Left(.Cells(i, "B").Text, 3) = "Id#" Then
                .Cells(i, "C").Value = True
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```